# Thread and GUI display

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {        
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
            if(event.getSource()==button[i]) {
                //button[i].setText(i+"");
                if(isFirstPlayer) {
                    button[i].setText(p1.symbol+"");
                    display.setText(p2.name + "'s turn");
                    isFirstPlayer=false;
                } else {
                    button[i].setText(p2.symbol+"");
                    display.setText(p1.name + "'s turn");
                    isFirstPlayer=true;
                }
                int result = getGameStatus();
                if(result!=NOT_FINISHED) {
                    if (result ==PLAYER1_WON) {
                        display.setText(p1.name + " won!");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for(int z=0;z<9;z++) {
                            button[z].setText("");
                        }
                        display.setText(p1.name+"'s turn");
                    } else if (result == PLAYER2_WON) {
                        display.setText(p2.name + " won!");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for(int z=0;z<9;z++) {
                            button[z].setText("");
                        }
                        display.setText(p2.name+"'s turn");
                    } else {
                        display.setText("Draw!");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        for(int z=0;z<9;z++) {
                            button[z].setText("");
                        }
                        display.setText(p1.name+"'s turn");
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

When I execute this, thread gets executed immediately where as I want to display the text first and then I want the thread to do its work...why is the thread getting invoked first and how can I correct it?

Comment: It's too hard to tell what is going on without more code.  What is "display"

Comment: consider it as this statement :

Comment: System.out.print(p1.name + " won!");

Comment: The Thread is NOT getting invoked first. It will do the System.out.println() before doing the sleep()

Comment: display here is an object of JTextArea.

Comment: Its not happening, that is the issue!

Comment: If you are on the swing thread, the problem might be that you are blocking the swing thread before it has a chance to repaint.  You never want to do Thread.sleep() on the swing thread.

Comment: Swing is single threaded, and sleeping in the event dispatch thread *blocks it*, so that no drawing can happen. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for delays.

Comment: So what should i do instead?...i want a delay there after the display.

Comment: Rather than concoct an answer, I'd really rather see your code.  I think you're misunderstanding more than one thing here.  Try to pair it down as best you can to show the problem.

Comment: okay wait just 1 min

Comment: I have edited the whole function now.

Answer (score 3):

The sleeping done by `Thread.sleep()` is done on the Event Dispatch Thread and that would lock the GUI.

So If you need to wait for a specific amount of time, don't sleep in the event dispatch thread. Instead, use a **[timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)**.

```
 int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //...Perform a task...
      }
  };
  new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```